# Can I set the parameters in an AWS CloudFormation launch URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to point my users to a cloudformation stack that they will need to run, but I'd like to be able to personalize it based on the user.  I've read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/construct-your-own-launch-stack-url/) and I would like to create a URL like:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/new?stackName=SomeName&MyParam=blah&templateURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/mytemplate.json

Notice the "MyParam=blah" in the middle.  The user can still change the parameter to whatever they want, but I'd like to be able to set a default.  Any ideas, other than writing a custom Cloudformation template per user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Update**]: As of [Jul 14 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/aws-cloudformation-adds-two-new-features-client-request-token-and-support-for-quick-create-links-in-the-cloudformation-console/), it is now possible to specify template parameters in URL query parameters provided to the launch stack URL. Use the `param_parameterName` format to specify template parameters, e.g.:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/create/review?stackName=SomeName&param_MyParam=blah&templateURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/mytemplate.json

See [Creating Quick-Create Links for Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-create-stacks-quick-create-links.html) for full details.

---

**[Original answer, Feb 10 2017]**:

It is not possible to preset default parameters directly via an AWS CloudFormation launch URL. `stackName` and `templateURL` are the only two URI fragment components that are parsed by the JavaScript code executed on this page.

Refer to the current [CloudFormation Console JavaScript source](https://d3l7tabrwpoxyr.cloudfront.net/js/9376120c64f4929c6ce92d08248f411e32306c9f/gzip/cloudformation_en.min.js) to confirm this, specifically the `parseRouteParams` function in the `StackInfo` object used by the `CreateStackController`:

```
this.parseRouteParams = function(a) {
    a = _.reduce(a, function(a, b, d) {
        a[d] = decodeURIComponent(b);
        return a
    }, a);
    _.extend(this, _.pick(a, "stackName", "templateURL"))
}
```

Here are some other ideas:

- Write some server-side code that dynamically renders the `Default` value of a Property in your CloudFormation template based on a provided query parameter, uploads the rendered template to an S3 bucket, then redirects to the create-stack page providing the URL to the newly-rendered template.
- Use another interface to the [CreateStack API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html) such as the AWS CLI [`create-stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html), or build your own web interface to dynamically provide default parameters.
- Write a custom User Script / browser extension that extends the Console page to parse the additional URI fragment parameter and inject the correct value into the Console input field directly.
- Ask AWS to add support for this feature directly into their URL parsing code.

Comment: This is what I thought.  Thank you for the thorough answer!  I found that minified cloudformation  javascript source but I couldn't pick out the part on what it was doing with the parameters.  Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

You can use our new quick launch URL to supply parameters to the Cloudformation Console. It supports Parameters using param_Foo syntax.

Here is an example for a sample APP

https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-central-1#/stacks/create/review?templateURL=https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-eu-central-1/WordPress_Single_Instance.template&stackName=MyWPBlog&param_DBName=mywpblog&param_InstanceType=t2.medium&param_KeyName=MyKeyPairUSEast1

Please note that this does not support deep linking for No Echo parameters, by design.

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-create-stacks-quick-create-links.html